# You did not provide any details for authentication. Error present on heroku not location machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, authlogic

I've recently pushed a commit to my heroku app which had nothing other than a migration. Since pushing the change my login section has returned the error "You did not provide any details for authentication." The bug doesn't happen on the local machine.

To test that the error was a result of the push I pushed the same changes to a different instance of the app and the same error started to occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1.5

Comment: Do you have an SSH key, and have you set up a username and pass with heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error still escapes us. No new gems and no Heroku updates since the 23rd. Nonetheless one of our developers solved the problem by adding `params.permit!`

With this in place AuthLogic began behaving as intended.